# Can you use the Foursquare API to get delivery availability

Tags: foursquare, yelp

In the yelp API they have a transactions response to return "pickup", "delivery", and "restaurant_reservation" if available.  Is there any equivalent with foursquare? Especially for delivery availability?

Answer (score 0):

The venues have an `attributes` property which may contain this info:

> Attributes associated with the venue, such as price tier, whether the
>   venue takes reservations, and parking availability.